# Play 2 - Access conf property in routes file

Tags: java, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

In older version of play, we could have written the following code in routes with somevar being defined in application.conf

```
%{
    somevar = play.Play.configuration.getProperty("somevar")
 }%

 GET  /${somevar}  controllers........
```

So we could have accessed the value of somevar in routes
Can anyone help me in accessing properties in routes from application.conf

Comment: My question here is accessing conf properties in routes file

Comment: Why whould you want to do this? Can you give an example in your question?

Comment: Suppose my application url is tagged with release version which would be present in application.conf
Example - say version v1.0 in first release, so my url endpoint would look like /v1.5/getAll
On next release, my version will become v1.1, so my url endpoint going to change.

Comment: Then just use a dynamic route with regex like: GET   /$v<[0-9]+>/getAll    controllers.YourController.getAll(). Then, in your controller you define the redirect() logic based on version number.

Comment: Did you read this? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaRouting. Or this? http://www.mariussoutier.com/blog/2012/12/11/playframework-routes-part-2-advanced/

Comment: I have read. BTW, we need to pass the v parameter even in that method. This things I do not have to do. It would look like unused parameter. Also in the next release I should not be able to access the old url endpoints. The one provided by you wont work in this scenario.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72683/discussion-between-deepak-and-sebster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I see absolutely no benefit from accessing vars in `application.conf` from the `routes` file. What's the difference between changing the value of a route in the `routes` file or `.conf` file. In both cases you need to change the value and restart the server for changes to take effect. So what's the trade?

In any case... here goes!

**Controller:**

```
public static Result getVersion(double var) {
    if (var != ConfigFactory.load().getDouble("version")) {
        return redirectTo();
    }
    return ok("version -> " + var);
}


public static Result redirectTo() {
    return redirect(controllers.routes.Application.getVersion(ConfigFactory.load().getDouble("version")));
}
```

**Route:**

```
GET     /redirect               controllers.Application.redirectTo()
GET     /:v/get                 controllers.Application.getVersion(v: Double)
```

**application.conf:**

version = 1.2

If you try to access an old endpoint you'll always get redirected to the version specified in application.conf.